# Vue Draggable - How to only replace item chosen to prevent shifting all other items on grid?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable

Here's an example to test:
https://codesandbox.io/s/j4vn761455?file=/src/App.vue:112-116

**Step 1**: Drag 4 to 5. As you see, 4 and 5 switch places

**Step 2**: Drag 1 to 6, as you see, 1 goes where 6 was, 6 gets pushed to the side, and 2, 3, 4, and 5 all shift over.

I would like though is to keep existing items untouched, moving 1 and 6 should move 1 to 6 and 6 to 1 space on the grid. All other items should remain in their spaces.

I have tried using `sort=false` this had no effect, and without a `group=`, it disables all dragging.

Is this possible?

I'd like the items in the grid to be stationary and only moved based on desired selection. If I'm not using the right tool, is there something else that could accomplish this? Think about if the grid was icons, it does make a good UI when moving icons to a selection and then all the previous icons automatically shift over. Would be very annoying to the user.

*Hope this makes sense, if you need more details, comment below and I'll revise/update as needed.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While vuedraggable does not provide swapping by default https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/466 , there's a great [article](https://okamuuu.com/posts/2019/2019-06-15.vue-draggable-to-be-swappable.html) that explains how to implement it yourself.

This is your modified code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vuedraggable-with-css-grid-forked-wk4xk

Basically, you need to implement the swapping behaviour yourself by storing the current and future indexes (note, I changed the name of your list to "items" just to make it easier to port the code in the article).

```
<draggable v-model="items" :move="handleMove" @end="handleDragEnd">
```

In your script

```
methods: {
    handleDragEnd() {
      this.futureItem = this.items[this.futureIndex];
      this.movingItem = this.items[this.movingIndex];
      const _items = Object.assign([], this.items);
      _items[this.futureIndex] = this.movingItem;
      _items[this.movingIndex] = this.futureItem;

      this.items = _items;
    },
    handleMove(e) {
      const { index, futureIndex } = e.draggedContext;
      this.movingIndex = index;
      this.futureIndex = futureIndex;
      return false; // disable sort
    }
  }
```

Comment: Oh, nice! Thanks for that. This looks like its exactly what I needed. question though, are you able to keep the `ghost` class intact?

Comment: Also good find. was reading it over, swap pull request just needs to be merged it to officially have that feature.

Comment: I just saw the PR; that would be the ideal solution. It's pretty bad that it seems to be stuck there since February, though. About the ghost class, no idea.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera Hi sir, How about replacing from another parameter. I badly needed

Comment: @AlbertoRivera https://stackoverflow.com/q/67254816/11845164

Comment: Your answer is already 3 years old but it still helped me today. Thanks a lot!