# VueDraggable - how can we be able to switch items from two different parameters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable

[This will be an update to this question][1] since we have the same problem but mine I want to be able to switch items from two different parameters. Currently I can only be able to switch items on from 1 parameter. I need your help by modifying this code so that it can be able to switch item from different parameter. I have tried modifying this for 5 hour but no luck. Thanks in advance.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
<!-- item1 -->
    <div>
      <draggable v-model="item1" :move="handleMove" @end="handleDragEnd">
        <transition-group tag="div" class="grid" name="grid">
          <div class="cell" v-for="item in item1" :key="item">{{ item }}</div>
        </transition-group>
      </draggable>
    </div>
<!-- item2 -->
    <div>
      <draggable v-model="item2" :move="handleMove" @end="handleDragEnd">
        <transition-group tag="div" class="grid" name="grid">
          <div class="cell" v-for="item in item2" :key="item">{{ item }}</div>
        </transition-group>
      </draggable>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>


<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      item1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
      item2: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleDragEnd() {
      this.futureItem = this.item1[this.futureIndex];
      this.movingItem = this.item1[this.movingIndex];
      const _items = Object.assign([], this.item1);
      _items[this.futureIndex] = this.movingItem;
      _items[this.movingIndex] = this.futureItem;

      this.item1 = _items;
    },
    handleMove(e) {
      const { index, futureIndex } = e.draggedContext;
      this.movingIndex = index;
      this.futureIndex = futureIndex;
      return false; // disable sort
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

cedits to: @Alberto Rivera for this code answerd on this question ->
[1]: [Vue Draggable - How to only replace item chosen to prevent shifting all other items on grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63433028/11845164)

Comment: I don't have time atm, but basically the idea is this:

1. Add an id to each of the draggable, and a group="myGroup"

2. In the handleMove, moving and future should contain both the id and the index

3. In handleDragEnd, use the ids and the indexes of moving and future to replace/arrange each of the lists as needed

Answer (score 1):

For Example.
If you selected an item on this.item1 create a condition if it exist on the other array. If it doesn't then it should be moving it to this.item2.